# Correct call mixpanel.identify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mixpanel

I`m use gems 'mixpanel-ruby' && 'devise'. When user sign up, i wrote

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    tracker = Mixpanel::Tracker.new('MIXPANEL_ID')
    email = params[:user][:email]
    distinct_id = params[:user][:distinct_id]
    tracker.alias(email, distinct_id)
    tracker.people.set(email, {
        '$email' => email,
    })
    tracker.track(email, "Sign up #{email}")
    super
  end
end
```

But when user open my web app from another computer, his distinct_id will other than the first. I guess need rewrite SessionController with action create, but mixpanel.identify() can be caused by javascript and not by ruby.
Who can help to understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make get district_id from cookie: cookie = document.cookie.split(";")[0]; distinct_id = cookie.substr(74,53); but correctly use regexp